# Exporting a topo map with custom borders to STL

Tags: qgis

I'm looking to 3D print topographic models of all 67 counties of Pennsylvania, with each county individually printed. I am using the DEMto3D plugin according to [this](http://depts.washington.edu/open3dp/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/Simplified_Process_to_3D_Print_Topo_Maps.pdf) guide.

My issue is that I would like each print to be in the shape of the county rather than the rectangle that the source .tif file comes in. Any guidance you have to offer? My apologies if I can't get into the jargon of this process, I am quite the newbie.